# Connecting to gtalk using jabber80.com on Pidgin

Tags: linux, pidgin, google-talk, jabber

how do I go about configuring pidgin so that I can connect to Gtalk using jabber80.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to say, that Googletalk can be used directly through port 443 or 80:

Go to the advanced tab and set the following options:

- [x] SSL/TSL
- [x] force legacy SSL
- [ ] cleartext authentification
- Port: 443
- Server: talk.google.com

But for all the users, who wants to use another provider which doesn't accept port 80 or 443 here is a desciption how to use jabber80.com:

You have to register a new account at jabber80.com by selecting "add this new account on the server" (or so - I use the german version of Pidgin).

Then you have to go to the advanced tab and set the following options:

- [x] SSL/TSL
- [x] force legacy SSL
- [ ] cleartext authentification
- Port: 443
- Server: jabber80.com

Now connect to the server and apply the registration.

Now you are registered at jabber80 and could add all your GTalk contacts to your Jabber80 list - if you don't want to move to this new server, use the jabber2jabber transport from jrudevels.org:

Activate the XMPP servive discovery plugin. Then run Tools->XMPP service dicovery -> XMPP service dicovery. click search and write jrudevels.org to the dialog and start the search. Now select the J2J-Transport, give the data of the XMPP-Account you normally use for chatting and activate the checkbox "import roaster". After activation you have to apply all the contact responses. It seems the Jrudevels server needs some time to import the presence status after the registration.

I think it would be better to use an J2J-Transport directly from jabber80.com, but it seems they don't provide such service at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Choose XMPP, and put [a jabber server](http://xmpp.org/services/) in the Domain field of Pidgin's account settings.